# Dualboot BlackArch Linux

Tags: linux, installation, multi-boot, arch-linux

I want to install Blackarch Linux however when I try to install it, it seems like it wants to delete my existing systems by claiming that my entire disk is "free space".

To start the installation I do `blackarch-install`, `Install from Live-ISO` and then I am not longer sure what I am suppose to do in order to setup dualbooting. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll need a bit more info on your setup. What other operating systems are installed? Have you already resized the partitions to allow for enough free space for a BlackArch install? Do you already have a vanilla Arch Linux install? Are you using a GUID Partition Table (GPT) or an MBR partition table? If it's an MBR partition table, how many primary partitions already exist on the disk?

Comment: @WilliamBonney I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, I already resized the partitions to make space for it, yes. No I don't have a vanilla arch install, I *think* I am used GPT just because MBR doesn't sound familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the additional info you gave me, I'm going to assume it's a sort of bug in the BlackArch installation software. My suggestion is to install vanilla Arch Linux, then install the BlackArch toolset within Arch Linux. On the BlackArch web site, under "Downloads", there's instructions for doing exactly this. The ArchLinux Wiki has an excellent beginner's guide for installing vanilla Arch as well.

Installing vanilla Arch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide

Installing BlackArch within vanilla Arch: http://blackarch.org/downloads.html

Also: BACKUPS. Just in case something goes wrong. :)

Comment: As much as I didn't like this approach, it was what I did and am pretty happy.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue.  I believe you see this because you are asked if you want to partition your device, which you must do if no suitable partitions are available.  If you say y to partitioning, you will then be asked if you want a "zeroed" disk to work with, which shows you the disk as it would look un-partitioned. If you choose this, all existing partitions will be over-written. Bad news if you don't want to replace Windows-despite the cracks.
The trick is, apparently, getting BlackArch to cooperate with you by adding Windows to its bootloader.  If you choose "no" to zeroing out the memory, and create a separate partition using already freed space, you could always  ... theoretically, direct the (Windows) (M)aster (B)oot (R)ecord to list BlackArch.  Ok. I'm lost.  Good luck!